# Why isn't my image changing on hover?

Tags: image, hover

I have tried moving the id around and putting both first and second images as a backround. Why isn't it working?

HTML

```
<div class="brandsCarousel">
    <ul>
        <li class="logo"><a href="#"><img id="logo-gpjbaker"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a #logo-gpjbaker {
    background-image: url(../images/logo-gpjbaker.png) center top no-repeat;
    max-width: 150px;
}

a #logo-gpjbaker:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/logo-gpjbaker2.png) center top no-repeat;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it it is not working is due to the space between your `a` and `#logo-gpjbaker:hover`

**http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/Jdaova**

It should be, this with no space:

```
a#logo-gpjbaker:hover {
    background: url(logo-gpjbaker2.png) center top no-repeat;
    max-width: 150px;

    display:block; /* add this */
    height:50px; /* add this */
}
```

Since your `id` is on your anchor tag or just use `#logo-gpjbaker:hover`

Also try setting your `a` anchor tag to `display:block` so it fills the entire space of its parent. Which should be used anytime when using an anchor tag as a trigger since its default display is set to inline.

Don't forget to set your `height` property as well.

Comment: added an example to my answer

Comment: That's great. I can't have it as `display: block` though. I have a list of other items to be displayed inline. What's the best way to size an image that's going to be on multiple pages?

Comment: the anchor tag can be `display:block` but its parent the `li` tag can have either `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` with the `float` property `left`

Comment: when you say `size and image` do you mean make your images responsive?

Comment: Not yet. I plan to use them slightly larger in other areas, so I was planning on making them a certain width/height...which is why I used the `<img>` tag first.

Comment: to make an image `img` tag responsive you just make your `max-width:100%` and height:`auto` but that wont work on a css background-image.. in that case you can look at css property `background-size` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a#logo-gpjbaker:hover
```

or this

```
#logo-gpjbaker:hover
```

Here you have a better example: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u3a8jr5g/)

Comment: The routes are correct? Have you tried to change background-color?

If you can add a fiddle I can help you better.

Comment: Yes, the link sources are correct. I tried using the long way and the short way. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/hywrpjyw/

Comment: Ah!! You can't change background of an img tag.

You should do <li class="logo"><a id="logo-gpjbaker" href="#"></a></li> and stablish a width and height or a padding to #logo-gpjbaker

Comment: Removed image and moved id. No luck :/